# rosdep install error

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I had following error when install rosdep to my oneiric-amd64 machine. Does anyone know what is the problem?

```
sudo easy_install -U rosdep
Searching for rosdep
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/rosdep/
Reading http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosdep
Reading http://pr.willowgarage.com/downloads/rosdep/
Best match: rosdep 0.8.0
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rosdep/rosdep-0.8.0.tar.gz#md5=09e0e4f52ba813ab540aac5715524e86
Processing rosdep-0.8.0.tar.gz
Running rosdep-0.8.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-C_3LU7/rosdep-0.8.0/egg-dist-tmp-rb_MJH
Traceback (most recent call last):
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rosdep/rosdep-0.8.0.tar.gz#md5=09e0e4f52ba813ab540aac5715524e86
Processing rosdep-0.8.0.tar.gz
Running rosdep-0.8.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-C_3LU7/rosdep-0.8.0/egg-dist-tmp-rb_MJH
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('distribute==0.6.16dev-r0', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1912, in main
    with_ei_usage(lambda:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1893, in with_ei_usage
    return f()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1916, in <lambda>
    distclass=DistributionWithoutHelpCommands, **kw
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 364, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 604, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 634, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 824, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1101, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1090, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 29, in run_setup
    lambda: execfile(
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 70, in run
    return func()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 31, in <lambda>
    {'__file__':setup_script, '__name__':'__main__'}
  File "setup.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "src/rosdep2/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    
  File "src/rosdep2/installers.py", line 39, in <module>
ImportError: No module named rospkg.os_detect
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28083/rosdep-install-error/) by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1186 on 2012-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to "pip install -U rospkg"

I'm fixing an issue right now that will make this problem go away with the next update.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on 2012-05-31**:
It worked for me, but had to use 'rosmake --pre-clean'.